# Web to mobile app converter

Tags: mobile, web, converters

I am looking for a **service / software** which **takes website and wraps it in a mobile application** for **iPhone and Android**. Without any additional features such as navigation or push messages. Just wrapping website + select app logo and name.

I am not able to find such a thing.

Maybe somebody knows?

Answer (score 0):

You can try ionicframework or jQuery mobile for converting web app (client side javascript) to mobile app. Which supports both android and iOS.

Comment: You can improve this answer greatly by providing a link to both Iconic Framework and JQuery Mobile as well as demonstrating how each would be used to address the question. In the meantime, your answer does not adequately address the question as asked.